# Show hook_form on specific content type Drupal 7 Programmaticaly

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

How can show a form that is created with the drupal _hook form api, on a specific content type? So, as example:

I created new content for the content type 'outside' when I click on save I see the content type like this:

- Titel
- Date
- Description

What I want is a form below this. I created one with a _hook form and it is working an saves data to my database but I have no idea, how can I show them on the same page as my content. It may not show on the content type 'inside'! Now it's a other page the link is /outside-form and only the form shows up there, no content type.

How can I get them below my content on every page that has the content type 'outside'? I have written a own module, but only this is not working/showing up on specific content(type).

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: please explain more in detail what you're trying to achieve. If you want a separate form, you can add it to the node form page using the block system.

Comment: You may use the Webform module for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a block that's content contains following code:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('YOUR_FORM_ID');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Set the block visiblity only on content type 'outside' & place this block in any region as per your suits.